# How should I design/implement an answer to a specific question in a Question-Answer system

Tags: php

I'm new to programming and asking your help to understand how I should design a Question-Answer system, in particular I'm stuck with one step that I can't figure out:

Say there is two persons: A and B. A sends multiple, different messages to B. B should be able to answer each of the messages separately. A then could see an answer to a particular question B answered. In other words, it should be some sort of a chain of messages.

I'm probably know how to build everything, however, I can't figure out how can I trace the particular message(that has been answered, for example). Of course I can use front-end tools, such as data attributes(etc) to attach id of each message(when retrieving it from the DB) and then be able to understand witch message was answered, but I don't like this idea, because it can be manipulated and modified by the user.

This is probably sounds very silly to experienced software developers like you, but I tried to think of everything and would appreciate your help.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: "    a specific programming problem, or
    a software algorithm, or
    software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
    a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"

Isn't this a "software algorithm" or "programming problem"?

Comment: Not really. You are asking a design question. Algorithm or problem would be much more specific. This is just too broad question.

Comment: Dharman, I don't get it why is this "too broad", do you mind to explain this please? I mean if it doesn't belong here - I'm ok with that, I'll delete it. But I think I was very specific about my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid giving the user a choice. (Here are some messages, which one are you replying to?).

It isn't possible to stop a user from completely controlling what they send in the HTTP response. They can tell you which message they are replying to. They can edit the response to claim to be replying to a different message. They can edit the response to claim not to be replying to a message at all.

You just have to write the server-side code to handle this.

Does the HTTP request indicate that the user is responding to a message? If so, is it a valid message id? If so, is it a message id of a message that the user is able to read in the first place? Is the response directed to the user who sent that message?

If any of the answers are "no", your code can either reject it entirely (presenting the user with an error), ignore the attempt to reply and treat it as a new message, or whatever else you deem appropriate.

Comment: This is exactly how I thought about this process! However, I'm stuck with what to do next after the above, rhetorical questions: How do I determine witch message was answered? Should I implement some sort of numeric index(additional) to track a chain of messages, so I could be able to determine what message was answered to what question/message. Or how should I be able to trace the messages that has been answered?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

A set of parameters in the request:

- chat_id: some id number to identify the instance of the conversation being done.
- user: the name of the user, be sure to verify this with cookies and some user authentication technique.
- message: the message the user sends.
- message_type: it would said whether the message is an answer or a question.
- question_id: some id number to identify the question. If not present, then the new message will be treated as the starter of a new question and will automatically be given an id number.
- show: whether to show the whole set of questions and answers made ("all"), or only show a specific question ("instance"). Defaults to "all".
- api: Output JSON data instead of HTML

To see the entire conversation:
`https://example.com/?chatid=some_id`

A asks a question:
`https://example.com/?chatid=some_id&user=A&message_type=question&message=the_question`

B replies a question:
`https://example.com/?chatid=some_id&user=A&message_type=answer&question_id=some_question_id&message=the_question`

A expands some previously made question:
`https://example.com/?chatid=some_id&user=A&message_type=answer&question_id=some_question_id&question_id=some_question&message=the_question`

Show only a specific question:

B replies a question:
`https://example.com/?chatid=some_id&question_id=some_question_id&show=instance`

Again, this is how it should be done:
1. A gets into the root page and immediately is assigned a chatid with B.
 - If only some users can ask and only some can reply then you should check that in your code.
 - B would have to get that same chatid too, possibly the chatid would be listed in another special page of unattended chats.
 - When a gets into the index and is assigned a chatid, generate the initial log register. YOU SHOULD BE SAVING ALL THE INPUT in either a database or in a JSON or XML file. Unless it will grow very big, I recommend making an array with the input messages of your users and converting it to JSON and saving it in a folder. Else use some database like MYSQL.
 - The page without questions nor answers should show a format to input a question.
2. A inputs a question, or many.
3. B reads the question, or the questions.
4. B replies the question, or the questions.
5. A makes another question, or expands the question made.

If you don't want to use javascript at all, then a solution can be worked out using iframes: put the page that shows the questions in an iframe that updates itself every some seconds, and put the page with the format to answer the questions in the main page or in another. However I recommend you to use javascript: Instead of doing the iframe thing, just load the page, and then update the sections of the page with javascript. You will just need to output a JSON text, instead of HTML text, from the very same PHP programme. So, for example, let's say that the usual thing is that your PHP programme will so do something like this in the end:

```
    echo $webpage;
```

Where $webpage is the HTML of your webpage.

Instead, you will output the array containing all the questions and answers (which should be something like `$chat = array([0] => ('question' = ([0] = 'question original', [1] = 'question expansion 1', [2] = 'question expansion 2'), 'answer' = ([0] = 'answer to question original', [1] = 'answer to question expansion 1', [2] = 'answer to question expansion 2')), [1] => ('question' = ([0] = 'question original', [1] = 'question expansion 1', [2] = 'question expansion 2'), 'answer' = ([0] = 'answer to question original', [1] = 'answer to question expansion 1', [2] = 'answer to question expansion 2')))`) in JSON.

Javascript would call the api at `https://example.com/?chatid=some_id&api=true` every second.

And your PHP will instead be like this:

```
     if($_GET['api'] == 'true') {echo json_encode($chat);} else {echo $webpage};
```

And then with javascript you will check whether the data is updated or not at the user side, and if it is not then will change the information showed in the screen, and the format so the user can send a new reply or a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to assign a unique (tracking number, alphnumeric, or character string) to each message. When an incomming answer (or reply) is received, look for the matching identifier and attach (or link) the response to the original message. If there is no match, either bounce it out or send a "potential risk" report up to the admin to trace. You could even track how many risk reports come from any given user so you can decide if they are trying to crack your site, or if there is a recurring glitch in the code.